# Split string on dots not preceded by a digit without losing digit in split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Given the following sentence:

```
The is 10. way of doing this. And this is 43. street.
```

I want preg_split() to give this:

```
Array (
 [0] => "This is 10. way of doing this"
 [1] => "And this is 43. street"
)
```

I am using:

```
preg_split("/[^\d+]\./i", $sentence)
```

But this gives me:

```
Array (
 [0] => "This is 10. way of doing thi"
 [1] => "And this is 43. stree"
)
```

As you can see, the last character of each sentence is removed. I know why this happens, but I don't know how to prevent it from happening. Any ideas? Can lookaheads and lookbehinds help here? I am not really familiar with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that:

```
preg_split("/(?<!\d)\./i",$sentence)
```

The difference is that `[^\d]+` would become part of the match, and thus `split` would remove it. The `(?!` assertion is also matched, but is "zero-width", meaning it does not become part of the delimiter match, and thus won't be thrown away.

Comment: I think you have to use negative lookbehind and not a negative lookahead i.e. `/(?<!\d)\./` Negative lookahead would fail to work according to OP's requirements.

Comment: You're right. Thanks! Looking at the preceding character was the intention here.

Answer (score 0):

To explode your string on literal dots that are not preceded by a digit, match the non-digit, then reset the fullstring match with `\K` (meaning "keep" from here), then match the "disposable" characters -- the literal dot and zero or more spaces.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jI608))

```
$string = 'The is 10. way of doing this. And this is 43. street.';
var_export(
    preg_split('~\D\K\. *~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/c4lsg))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('~(?<!\d)\. *~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cGDFZ))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('~(?<=\D)\. *~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output: (all clean, no trailing dots, no trailing spaces, no unexpected lost characters)

```
array (
  0 => 'The is 10. way of doing this',
  1 => 'And this is 43. street',
)
```